# In App Billing in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on an app In which I have to make the  functionality of purchasing magazines.Therefore i need to implement InAppBilling.
I read the documentation from this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html
& get the sample code of InApp Billing & make changes as suggested in the Documentation.
After signing the app i had upload the .apk as draft & set the items their ids,Price & then publish that items as in   http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-catalog
& then i upload it in the Google Play Shop.But when i download it from the Google Play Shop it doesn,t show me the Product list & price of the item even i had published the item.
Can anyone suggest me any solution or give an another way to do this.

Thanks....

Comment: Maybe an easier tutorial for you is: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode product list into your application, as far as I know, there's no way your app can download product list from the Google Market.

Comment: How can i encode the product list in the app as in the demo app there is not such method where i  have to put the product list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no market API that gives you a list of products. You will need to keep the list of products in your application. And if you want to show a description also, that also you will need to keep it within your app.

Alternatively, if you want to make it dynamic, then you will be better off keeping this list somewhere, and then have the app look up there for the list of products and there descriptions.